# Can I remove preinstalled Local Experience Packs?

Tags: windows-10, windows-store

I just got a new laptop, and in the MS Store, I keep getting updates for about 20 Local Experience Packs, for languages I'll never use.  I found some references that suggest using the Language tab in Settings to remove them, but only the language I'm currently using is listed there.  I also found the PowerShell command `Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *LanguageExperiencePack*`, which lists all of them, but when I pipe one or more of the discovered packages to `Remove-AppxPackage`, it briefly flashes a progress bar at the top of the console, but the pack is not removed.

Is it impossible to uninstall these packs?

Comment: Can you provide the output of Get-WinUserLanguageList for us?

Answer (score 2):

First, ensure that you run the powershell "as Admin" (even if your user is an "Admin").

Second, when you run the -AllUsers you need to use it on the remove side too. Also, try doing them individually like this:

`Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers -Package "<insert full appx name here>"`

If that works, then you could try to pipe the Get- into the Remove- command.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is sound advice, but my actual problem turned out to be that when you run the `Remove-AppxPackage`, it doesn't appear to impact the output of subsequent `Get-AppxPackage` commands *until after a reboot*.  I've rebooted since posting the question, and all the offending packages are gone now.  Nice to know; I don't think any of the how-to articles I saw mentioned that.